# What would the maximum current draw for this chip be?

Tags: current, digital-logic, switches

I am looking at using this logic switch in my circuit:

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FSTD16211-D.pdf

Looking at the datasheet I am finding it hard to figure out what the maximum current draw would be.

As far as I can see, I need to supply:

5v drawing potentially up to (what)mA?

Am I safe to assume that it will be 5v and definitely under 100mA? I need to know so I choose the correct level shifter supplying the 5v!

Many thanks!

Comment: Bit strange yes. 7 ohms times the current squared will give you the heat dissipation in watt, but without the thermal resistance (K/W), you can only estimate how much headroom there is.

Comment: shall I assume that it will be 5v and definitely under 100mA? I need to know so I choose the correct level shifter supplying the 5v!

Comment: But what is your output or downstream load current?

Comment: On page 3: **Incraese in \$I_{CC}\$ per Cotrol Input = 2.5mA max** + **Quiescent Supply Current = 1.5mA**.  There are only two control inputs.

Comment: Ok so that means it would likely draw a max current of 8mA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the maximum current is 61.5mA. 24 inputs at 2.5mA and the quiescent current of 1.5mA. That current will occur with all inputs at 3.4V. If any of the inputs are at Vcc or 0V the current will be less.

If you look at an older version of the [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/159100/FAIRCHILD/FSTD16211.html), it seems apparent they are referring to inputs, not control inputs.

[image]

Comment: Which suggests @stainlesssteelrat comment above misinterprets the datasheet?

Comment: I think the "new" datasheet is misleading.